# Chart from d3.js to file without displaying on a page first

Tags: d3.js, fpdf

I am new to `d3` but I am hoping that it possible to create a chart in `d3` and output the chart to a file without displaying it on a page first. Is it? I would like to include various charts in a `pdf` document using `fpdf` and import into the `pdf` a chart or two.

I have been searching around for a solution to this for some time now. While I can see that you can:

- Use d3 (chart.js etc) to generate a chart and display it on screen in a page
- Export the image to file on the server
- And then create the pdf importing the saved image

But I want to avoid any on screen display and for the image of the chart to be saved to the server directly so that `fpdf` can import it in.

This seems to me something that would be required frequently but I can't seem to find a solution.

An option seems to be to use something like phantomjs as an interim step but I think that this needs to be running on my host. It would be great if it could be exported to file driectly from d3. Is this possible?

Comment: You could avoid showing anything actually on the screen by using CSS to ensure it stays out of the viewable area, but unless you use PhantomJS you'd need that browser step.  Submitting the SVG data to something like batik rasterizer would allow you to generate a file which would then be available to fpdf.

Comment: Thanks. Ended up with pChart server side chart generator. Not bad and seems to work ok. Not d3 though.